# Aliases for loaders in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is it possible to assign aliases for loaders in webpack ?

Usage:

```
image: function(opts) {
  return "image-size?name=[name]-[hash:8].[ext]"
}
css: function(opts) {
  return "style?singleton!css?sourceMap&module&localIdentName=[path][name]_[local]_[hash:base64:6]!postcss"
}
```

I get that this is how to file extensions are used, and can become an unnecessary entity.

I'm looking for a solution where I want to be able to write a long loader and have only one option to be used when using in require.

say,

```
require('./file1.png?size=10')
require('./file2.png?size=15')

// at one place require it as component
// passing through a set of loaders
var Component = require('react-svg!./image.svg')
// and in another require it as data-uri
// passing through a different set of loaders
var imagestr = require('data-uri!./image.svg')
// and in css
url( image!./image.svg )
```

Comment: I strongly encourage you to not use loader syntax in `require`. `require` has a specific meaning in CommonJS modules, and Webpack users are devaluing that meaning, making the code less semantic and incompatible with the far more popular Node.js form of `require`. Aliases do the same thing. It's far cleaner and community-compatible to do it the NPM way—require in a module using it's name. That makes it easy to see exactly what is happening form your code, where to get documentation, where to look on Github etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use aliases for loaders in [resolveLoader](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolveloader) section in your config, but in one alias you can define only one loader:

```
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        'my-image': 'image-size?name=[name]-[hash:8].[ext]',
        'my-style': 'style?singleton',
        'my-css': 'css?sourceMap&module&localIdentName=[path][name]_[local]_[hash:base64:6]'
    }
},
```

so your code will be like this:

```
require('my-image!./image.svg');
require('my-style!my-css!postcss!./style.css');
```

Comment: How can I use this loader using the `loaders` array? for example: `loaders: [{test: /\.png$/, loader: 'my-image']`